# Create an empty data frame with index from another data frame

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I've got a data frame **df1** with multiple columns and rows. Simple example:

```
    TIME T1  T2 
       1 10 100
       2 20 200
       3 30 300
```

I'd like to create an empty data frame **df2** and later on, add new columns with the calculation results.

For this moment my code looks like this:

```
     df1=pd.read_csv("1.txt",index_col="TIME")

     df2=df1.copy()[[]] #copy df1 and erase all columns
```

...adding two new columns:

```
     df2["results1"],df2["results2"]=df1["T1"]*df["T2"]*3,df1["T2"]+100
```

Is there any better/safer/faster way to do this ? 
Is it possible to create an empty data frame df2 and only copy index from df1 ?

Comment: I like your original suggestion, except you don't have to copy and erase the whole dataframe: df2=df1[[]].copy() #empty slice, then copy

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index)
```

This will create a DataFrame with no columns but just an index, and it will be the same index as in the df1.

Comment: It's better set index as df1.index.copy(); otherwise, df1 and df2 will share the same index object

Comment: Indexes are immutable exactly for this reason.

Comment: While you set df2.index.name = 'test', df1's index will also get the name.

Comment: The bug will be fixed in the [next version](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4202), so it's better use df1.index.copy() before 0.13 released

Answer (score 15):

It's better to set index as df1.index.copy()

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index.copy())
```

You can use `df1.index` is `df2.index` to check whether they are the same object

Comment: It's not, you just make an unnecessary copy of an index. Indexes are immutable exactly for this reason - to be able to share them among different data structures without a fear that they gonna change.

Answer (score 11):

You can also assign the index of a dataframe to another dataframe directly.

`df2.index=df1.index`

Comment: The lengths of the indices must match though, otherwise you get a `ValueError`  for `Length mismatch`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this short code:

`df2=df1[[]].copy()`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid geting all the `NaN` after the concat add the index to it.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1.toarray(),index=simpledf.index, columns=v.get_feature_names())
```

When defining the new dataframe with `X` transformed use the same index as the original dataframe.

Comment: This is a very good reminder!