# How can I check feature values for a predict value in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am doing a binary classification, predicted values are 0 and 1, is there is any way to get features values for a prediction value.

for eg:
I have 2 features 'Age' and 'Salary' and target value is 'purchased'.
Age  Salary   Purchased
19   19000       0
35   20000       0
27   30000       1
41   29000       1
65   40000       1

So, I want to know for each test case outcome (0 or 1) what were features values (Age and Salary).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = df.iloc[:,[0,1]]
y = df.iloc[:,2]


from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test =train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
regressor = LogisticRegression()
regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred=regressor.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: When you say you want to know, what do you mean by this? `x_test` has all of your features at the same index as their predictions in `y_pred`. Are you looking for a way to combine them into a single data structure? Create a visualization of their relationship?

Comment: You can take a look here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html, maybe you want something to do with `regressor.coef_` or `regressor.intercept_`

Comment: yes,i want to know how to combine x_test and y_pred so that end user can visualize it clearly @morsecodist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification that you just want to put them in the same data structure. You can [concatenate two dataframes with pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). But you need to put the predictions [within a dataframe with the appropriate index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176933/create-an-empty-data-frame-with-index-from). Here is the code:

```
y_pred_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, index=x_test.index)
pd.concat([x_test, y_pred_df], axis=1)
```